# What is the correct molecular orbital diagram for the d orbitals in platinum for the tetraammineplatinum(II) complex?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, molecular-orbital-theory

I am trying to construct the diagram of $\mathrm{d}$ orbitals in the  tetraammineplatinum(II) complex. According to the angular overlap model, $\mathrm{d}$ orbitals are going to look like those in the picture. However, planar square complexes are drawn completely differently according to other approaches and this makes me doubt the validity of my diagram.

To arrive to this diagram, I used the following table:<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

[image]

As $\ce{NH3}$ is a σ only ligand, I am not taking into account the π interactions, for which there is a separate table. In the square planar shape, the ligands in the 1 and 6 positions are absent, so they do not contribute to the rise of the d orbital energies, only the 2, 3, 4, and 5 positions do.  According to this, the $\mathrm{d}_{z^2}$ orbital should be raised in energy by $(1/4)+(1/4)+(1/4)+(1/4)=1 \mathrm{e}_\sigma$, and $\mathrm{d}_{x^2-y^2}$ should be raised by $(3/4)+(3/4)+(3/4)+(3/4)= 3 \mathrm{e}_\sigma$. The rest of the orbitals should stay the same energy they are as their coefficients are zero.

[image: AOM sigma-only square planar splitting]

Is this a correct diagram for a planar square coordination complex, with sigma only ligands, such as $\ce{[Pt(NH3)4]2+}$?

Comment: What is the angular overlap model? If you are considering crystal field theory then your diagram doesn't look right. Take a look at the diagram in this page: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Crystal_Field_Theory/Crystal_Field_Theory

Comment: It's a way of predicting the energies of the d orbitals in a complex. I read about it in an Inorganic Chemistry textbook by Gary. L. Miessler.

Comment: Hmm I have never heard of that method, but I feel that both methods should give the same result. Perhaps you could share all of the steps that you did in the calculation?

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti I could show but I do not see any point in that if you are not familiar with the theory of Angular overlap model already, no offense. I do acknowledge that this diagram not the same that is given by CFT. However, I was thinking that maybe this incompatibility is due to CFT being a simplistic approach compared to angular overlap model.

Comment: @Holyshmarckel Even though Shoubhik isn't familiar with the concept, you should add the details. In a couple of days this question this question will get many views and there is a high likelihood that someone who is familiar with the concept will find it.

Comment: I also hadn't come across AOM previously, possibly because it fits in a somewhat small niche between the mostly qualitative crystal/ligand field theory and the more quantitative semiempirical electronic structure methods like Huckel theory.  Based on question 10.15 of this [solution sheet](https://www.chem.uci.edu/~lawm/Ch%2010%20Solutions.pdf), you have the right idea. While this question was for a square pyramidal splitting, it seems clear from your table that in going to square planar, the xy/xz/yz orbitals would be unaffected and z^2 would shift down by 1 sigma as you suggest.

Comment: @Tyberius What I drew is definitely what AOM predicts to be the d orbital energies of metal & sigma only ligand complex. Your solutions sheet supports that and my math makes sense. But is it a correct diagram empirically or according to LFT?

Comment: @Holyshmarckel yes, if you used LFT, you would get the same qualitative result. This is because $t_{2g}$ orbitals are nonbonding (since there are only $\sigma$ interactions), so their energies won't change when going from octahedral $\ce{[Pt(NH3)6]^2+}$ to square planar $\ce{[Pt(NH3)4]^2+}$. But as you remove the ligands on $z$-axis, there will be less overlapping with $d_{z^2}$ so it will decrease in energy because $e_{g}^*$ is antibonding in this case.

Comment: @Tyberius Ligand field theory is only an application of molecular orbital theory, so from a purely theoretical point of view it should be complete. The question then becomes how do you approach it and how do you (approximately) solve it. In general, you could be exact, but phenomenological you don't need to be. Crystal field theory on the other hand uses orbitals without describing bonding. From what I have gathered so far, the angular overlap method is (again) rooted in LFT (=MOT), so it must produce the same result (at least approximately or qualitatively).

Comment: I have inserted a placeholder for a proper citation. I have to be brutally honest here: There are two ways this question may be read, and in both ways, there need to be more details/ more context about the AOM. Apparently this technique is niche or at least not common, so an overview and links must be included. One way of reading the question would then be: Does AOM correctly reproduce the MO diagram for the complex? The other one is: What is the MO diagram for the complex, I have used AOM to solve it. As of now, I *personally* would consider this question off-topic. cc @SRMaiti

Comment: This looks like a fun and interesting read: Suta, M.; Cimpoesu, F.; Urland, W. The angular overlap model of ligand field theory for f elements: An intuitive approach building bridges between theory and experiment. *Coord. Chem. Rev.* **2021,** *441,* 213981. [DOI: 10.1016/j.ccr.2021.213981](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ccr.2021.213981).

Comment: @Tyberius maybe you could write the answer for this question? I know you gave it in comments but as this question is bountied I think someone didn't see it here

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I interpreted this question as "does AOM correctly reproduce the MO diagram for the complex" which then ties into "what is the MO diagram of the complex?" as you mention. I personally don't feel this question is off-topic imho, despite AOM being a somewhat niche.

Comment: @SRMaiti that is the whole point of the comment: we shouldn't have to fall back to interpretation of the question, it should be clear from the start. To me it isn't, and that is why I'd consider it rather off-topic. And that is only tangential to AOM being niche. That's just contributing to the confusion. It would be a great question, if there was an actual source for those tables and a brief explanation. But anyway, my opinion doesn't count here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have correctly produced the diagram according to the angular overlap model, and the result is qualitatively in agreement with what you would get from other models. The reason it looks different from some canonical diagrams that you may find in textbooks for square planar complexes where *d*<sub>xy</sub> is raised in energy is because of the lack of $\pi$ interactions in this complex. It is the $\pi$ interactions that affect the *d*<sub>xy</sub> in the more general case.

Also, a general comment on the AOM since it seems not to be widely known. For what it's worth, it is described in the lecture notes that Richard Holm distributed for his undergraduate Inorganic Chemistry class at Harvard University in the 90's. He describes it thus:

> The **Angular Overlap Model (AOM)** is a simple first approximation to the full MO model and embodies all of the characteristics of metal-ligand interactions important to understanding of the principles of structure, magnetism, and absorption spectra (color). Its primary value is the rapid establishment of d-orbital degeneracies (or lack thereof) and relative energies. It provides a guide to the metal-ligand orbital interactions as a basis of geometric and electronic structure and reactivity of ML<sub>n</sub> complexes. The model utilizes two parameters:

> $e_\sigma$: $*$ a parameter defining energies of d-orbitals involved in $\sigma$-bonding in a given molecule
> $*$ depends on the overlap integral and $d_{z^2}$/L$\sigma$ energy difference; always positive

> $e_\pi$: $*$ a parameter defining energies of d-orbitals involved in $\pi$-bonding in a given molecule
> $*$ +ve --$\pi$ donor
> $*$ -ve --$\pi$ acceptor

This text is taken from the 1996 version of the lecture notes for Chemistry 40: Inorganic Chemistry written by R.H. Holm. The pages are not numbered. Given Holm's stature in the inorganic chemistry community and the general reputation of the Harvard chemistry department, I would assume that the approach was more widely accepted and taught (at least at that time), but I do not have evidence of that. Perhaps someone can add a reference to a commercially published text?

**UPDATED REFERENCE**: The AOM is also described in detail (with many references) in

Cotton, F.A., and Wilkinson, G.  Advanced Inorganic Chemistry 4th Edition, John Wiley & Sons, 1980, p.652-655.

Given the popularity of this text, I would argue that AOM was more than a niche model, though quite possibly no longer taught.

Comment: +1 But perhaps adding diagrams (MO or AOM) of the sigma-only and sigma+pi bonding case would make the answer more easily understandable?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot take any book seriously, if they abbreviate positive and negative in that form.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン as noted, it's lecture notes, not a book. If you want formal writing, read the cited section in Cotton and Wilkinson.

Comment: The Angular Overlap model is still appreciated, at least at the research level. I don't know how much it is taught. See this very recent Coordination Chemistry Reviews "The angular overlap model of ligand field theory for f elements: An intuitive approach building bridges between theory and experiment" https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ccr.2021.213981